# Importing photos finds all image files, not just camera pictures, with windows 7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera, windows, import

Importing files with windows7 will detect all phone photo files and not just those under camera/DCIM directory , want to use windows so can change files names same way as when importing from camera, I know there are other programs, thanks, would appreciated tips how to do it importing with windows 7 resident program.